# xlwings add in for python 3.6.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlwings

I've just installed the xlwings add-in through anaconda. But if I type in the `import xlwings` command in the Python shell I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import xlwings
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlwings'
```

If I enter the `import xlwings` command into the windows command prompt everything is fine. Can someone tell me how to fix this problem with the Python shell?

I am on a Windows 10 and Excel 2016.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by "the Python shell" and "the Windows command prompt". I am guessing by *Windows command prompt* you mean the Python command-line interpreter, `python.exe` and I understand that works as expected. What are you doing to run "the Python shell", which, as I understand it, doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: The windows command prompt refers to cmd.exe and the python shell is also known as the IDLE. But I think I've just figured out what the problem is. I think it's because I've installed python a second time with Anaconda. When I am using the Spyder IDE Python connects to excel without any problems but when using the "old" python it cannot import the xlwings add-in.

Comment: Your assessment looks to me to be 100% correct. I also have several installations (Python 3.7, Python 3.6, ...) and I find it pays to take the trouble to do library installs in each of them, because it's much easier to get it right at the time, than to wait and have to work out afterwards what is missing.